# Install python ssl module on linux without recompiling

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

Is it possible to install the SSL module for python on a linux box that already has OpenSSL installed without recompiling python?  I was hoping it would be as simple as copying over a few files and including them in the library path.  Python version is 2.4.3.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to install the SSL module for python on a linux box that already has OpenSSL installed without recompiling python?

Yes. Python's `setup.py` uses the following logic to detect OpenSSL:

```
search_for_ssl_incs_in = [
                      '/usr/local/ssl/include',
                      '/usr/contrib/ssl/include/'
                     ]

ssl_incs = find_file('openssl/ssl.h', inc_dirs,
                     search_for_ssl_incs_in

ssl_libs = find_library_file(self.compiler, 'ssl',lib_dirs,
                             ['/usr/local/ssl/lib',
                              '/usr/contrib/ssl/lib/'
                             ] )

if (ssl_incs is not None and
    ssl_libs is not None):
    exts.append( Extension('_ssl', ['_ssl.c'],
                           include_dirs = ssl_incs,
                           library_dirs = ssl_libs,
                           libraries = ['ssl', 'crypto'],
                           depends = ['socketmodule.h']), )
```

The point is Python is *not* static linking against `libssl` and `libcrypto`. (Some static linking occurs with `cctyes`, but nothing else).

Now, the bad thing is that the project uses system paths *before* your locally installed paths. For example, the project uses `inc_dirs` (system) *before* `search_for_ssl_incs_in` (local). (See more on this below).

After you run `configure`, you will have a `Modules/Setup` with the following lines commented out:

```
# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
#SSL=/usr/local/ssl
#_ssl _ssl.c \
#   -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
#   -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Again, no static linking. (And this assumes the previous version of Python uncommented those lines).

So you should be able to build a *binary compatible* version of OpenSSL and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PREOLAD` to ensure Python uses your updated version of OpenSSL.

OpenSSL 0.9.7 and  0.9.8 are binary compatible. OpenSSL 1.0.0, 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 are binary compatible. OpenSSL 0.9.8 and 1.0.0 are *not* binary compatible.

### ----------

Here's the problem with Python's setup placing system includes *before* local includes:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/ssl/darwin/include"; export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/ssl/darwin/lib"
<edit Setup search_for_ssl_incs_in and search_for_ssl_incs_in>
./configure
<edit Modules/Setup>
make
...
/Users/jww/Python-3.4.2/Modules/_ssl.c:390:9: warning: 
      'ERR_peek_last_error' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    e = ERR_peek_last_error();
        ^
/usr/include/openssl/err.h:274:15: note: 'ERR_peek_last_error' declared here
unsigned long ERR_peek_last_error(void) DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_1...
              ^
/Users/jww/Python-3.4.2/Modules/_ssl.c:393:15: warning: 
      'SSL_get_error' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        err = SSL_get_error(obj->ssl, ret);
...
```

Python used the down level version 0.9.8 version of OpenSSL provided by Apple, and not my recent OpenSSL 1.0.1k. That's despite me (1) exporting them in `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`; (2) editing `Setup`; and (3) editing `Modules/Setup`.

And I still have runtime path problems to contend with, so I'll need to use `LD_PRELOAD_PATH`, `DYNLIB_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc.

Comment: Doesn't this require the source for python?  I am trying to do this with no source.  You may have explained that, but I misunderstood.

Comment: It looks like there is no other way for python to use ssl without compiling it.

Comment: @Hassek - yes and no. If you use a binary compatible OpenSSL 0.9.8, then No, there's no need to recompile Python. However, OpenSSL 0.9.8 is End-of-Life (EOL) and it lack most ECC and TLS 1.2, so you probably want to avoid it. OpenSSL 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 are the way to proceed, and in case, Yes, you must recompile Python. Its easy to recompile once you know where to look for the SSL bits (as shown above).

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** Python >= 2.6 already has SSL support built-in, there's no need to install `ssl` package.

Install package from pypi:

```
pip install ssl
```

If you're missing `pip` command, install it for your distribution:

RedHat/Centos:

```
yum install python-pip
```

Debian/Ubuntu

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: The ubuntu box I am using is not connected to the internet.

Comment: Can you use a usb stick/external drive on the machine? If so just download the .tar.gz file to the usb stick on another machine (that can access the internet) then pop the usb stick into the ubuntu box and do "pip install /home/username/ssl-1.16.tar.gz". Obviously you need to replace /home/username with the path to the file.

Comment: pip is not installed on this version of linux, can you do something similar with yum?

Comment: This is useless, this is what happens when you run `pip install ssl`

`pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

Shocker...