# Cannot install pip from get-pip.py

Tags: python, pip, installation

I'm working on a remote Linux system without root permission. I want to install python and pip locally. I have managed to install python, but failed on pip. The command I use is as follows:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py --user
```

The downloading succeeded, but when running the second command, I received the error message:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

I also tried

```
python get-pip.py
```

But the error is the same.
What's wrong with my commands?
Thank you all for helping me!!!

Comment: how did you install python? The error is saying python was not compiled with ssl support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952343/install-python-ssl-module-on-linux-without-recompiling perhaps try: `apt-get install python-pip` or `yum install python-pip` also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location or reinstall python using the distributions package manager `apt-get` or `yum` or whatever it is.

Comment: I install python by wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tgz

Comment: and then extract, install, export the PATH, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will find that can't `import ssl` too.

The solution is:

1. Install openssl, `yum install openssl openssl-devel`
2. Configure source code
3. then open `Modules/Setup`, and un-comment following part

   ```
   #SSL=/usr/local/ssl
   #_ssl _ssl.c \
   #       -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
   #       -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
   ```
4. `make & make install` python from source code